# Use Poisson Brackets to show that $Q$ generates the transformation $q_i \to q_i +a$ where $a$ is a constant and $i=\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

I am given the Lagrangian $L= \frac{1}{2}(\dot q_1^2 +\dot q_2^2 + \dot q_3^2) -e^{q_1-q_2} - e^{q_2-q_1}$

And firstly I am asked to find what $Q$ is, using Noether's theorem under the transformation

$q_i \to q_i +a$ where $a$ is a constant and $i=\{1,2,3\}$

So I showed that this transformation was invariant and got the $Q = \dot q_1 +\dot q_2 + \dot q_3$

Then the question asks me to express Q as canonical momenta, now I am not really sure what this means, so I guess it meant put $Q =p_1 +p_2 +p_3$

Then the question asks me to find 2 functions $A$ and $B$ and use the poisson brackets $\{A,B\}$ to show that $Q$ generates the transformations earlier specified.

So I guess that one of the functions must be $Q$ but I don't know how to figure out what the other function should be to get the transformations required.

Comment: You got the wrong $Q$. This is a simultaneous translation of all three coordinates by $a$ (i.e. in the direction $\hat{e}_1 + \hat{e}_2 + \hat{e}_3$). Thus you would expect a momentum that is a linear combination of standard momenta parallel to $\hat{e}_1 + \hat{e}_2 + \hat{e}_3$. In other words, it should be linear in the $\dot{q}_i$.

Comment: are you saying that it should be $Q = a\dot q_1^2 +a\dot q_2^2 + a\dot q_3^2$ ???? Normally for Neother's theorem I know you times by the value in front of $\epsilon$ in the transformation. But there is no epsilon here. Could you possibly tell me the answer to my question as I am stressing about this very much so and have an exam in it tomorrow

Comment: I just realised what you meant. That was actually a typo on my behalf, sorry

Comment: No. $a$ plays the role of $\epsilon$ here. You might be able to better see what's going on if you look at this in a rotated coordinate system. Consider the coordinates: 
\begin{align}
Q_1 &= \frac{q_1 - q_2}{\sqrt{2}} \\
Q_2 & = \frac{q_1 + q_2 - 2 q_3}{\sqrt{6}} \\
Q_3 & = \frac{q_1 + q_2 + q_3}{\sqrt{3}},
\end{align}
You get Lagrangian $$L = \frac{1}{2} (\dot{Q}_1^2 + \dot{Q}_2^2 + \dot{Q}_3^2) - 2 \cosh [Q_1  \sqrt{2}].$$

In these coordinates the transformation is entirely confined to the $Q_3$ coordinate.

Comment: @SeanLake Yeah sorry about that too, I think what I have in the original question is right now. But the question asks to show that this transformation can be achieved by using the poisson brackets and Q and I don't really know what to do. I've been trying for hours

Comment: Take $A(p_i, q_i)$ and stick it in Poisson brackets with $p_i$, the generator of translations in $q_i$. What do you get? Off the top of my head (so sign may be wrong): $\{A,p_j\} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial q_j}$. That's the pattern of $p_j$ generating translations in the $q_j$ direction on the space of functions $A$ lives in. What does $\{A, Q\}$ come out to be? Is it (up to a multiplicative constant) the directional derivative of $A$ in the direction of the transformation (it should be)?

Comment: @SeanLake Ok, so are you trying to say that I should like set $A=\frac {q_i^2}{2} + aq_i$ ? Because then $\{A,Q\}$ will give me what I require. This is for $i=\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59328/discussion-between-sean-lake-and-daniel-mcelroy).